# norm parameters in sklearn.preprocessing.normalize

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization

In [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) says "norm" can be either

> norm : ‘l1’, ‘l2’, or ‘max’, optional (‘l2’ by default)
> The norm to use to normalize each non zero sample (or each non-zero feature if axis is 0).

[The documentation about normalization](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-normalization) isn't clearly stating how ‘l1’, ‘l2’, or ‘max’ are calculated.

Can anyone clear these?

Comment: Do you know what a norm is? Did you consider creating a simple dataset and try those 3 candidates? Where is the problem? This kind of analysis probably would have been faster than asking for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Informally speaking, the norm is a generalization of the concept of (vector) length; from the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)):

> In linear algebra, functional analysis, and related areas of mathematics, a **norm** is a function that assigns a strictly positive *length* or *size* to each vector in a vector space.

The [L2-norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html) is the usual Euclidean length, i.e. the square root of the sum of the squared vector elements.

The [L1-norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L1-Norm.html) is the sum of the absolute values of the vector elements.

The [max-norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L-Infinity-Norm.html) (sometimes also called infinity norm) is simply the maximum absolute vector element.

As the docs say, normalization here means making our vectors (i.e. data samples) having unit length, so specifying *which* length (i.e. which norm) is also required.

You can easily verify the above adapting the examples from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#normalization):

```python
from sklearn import preprocessing 
import numpy as np

X = [[ 1., -1.,  2.],
     [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  1., -1.]]

X_l1 = preprocessing.normalize(X, norm='l1')
X_l1
# array([[ 0.25, -0.25,  0.5 ],
#        [ 1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
#        [ 0.  ,  0.5 , -0.5 ]])
```

You can verify by simple visual inspection that the absolute values of the elements of `X_l1` sum up to 1.

```python
X_l2 = preprocessing.normalize(X, norm='l2')
X_l2
# array([[ 0.40824829, -0.40824829,  0.81649658],
#        [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.        ,  0.70710678, -0.70710678]])

np.sqrt(np.sum(X_l2**2, axis=1)) # verify that L2-norm is indeed 1
# array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
```